# Symfony 1.4 or Symfony 2.0 beta for non-symfony starter using php web frameworks

Tags: symfony, symfony1, php

I am new to using Symfony, and I finally settled on it after trying both CodeIgniter and CakePHP for nearly month each.

I have a sufficient know-how with web frameworks but absolutely no idea for Symfony framework.
Now I am in a bit of confusion here since Symfony 2.0 beta is here.

I just wanted to know should I start learning Symfony 2.0 beta or Symfony 1.4, considering the future expectations. Symfony has a tough learning curve and hence, I don't want to go through it again later.

Comment: Check in the Symfony thread. This is a repeated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why start to learn an "outdated" technology? Consider the following:

- [Symfony2 is not in beta anymore!](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-2-0-rc1-released)
  This means the code is (should be)
  stable, and thus ready for
  production.
- Symfony 1.4 (although it is great, I
  must say) has an end of maintenance
  date of November, 2012.
- Performance wise, Symfony2 is much,
  much better than Symfony 1.4
- Symfony2 uses [Doctrine 2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/en) as ORM
  (although others can be used) and the
  [Twig template system](http://www.twig-project.org/), and both
  of them are (in my opinion) the best
  out there.
- Symfony2 uses PHP version 5.3, which
  has great new functionalities. This
  should be the only point to watch 
  carefully, since many
  production servers still don't
  support PHP 5.3, but I guess this
  should change over time.

Since you quote "future expectations", I wouldn't think it twice and jump into Symfony2.